# Avoid duplicated records in nullable relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a player table:

```
-------------------------
| id    | name  | email |
-------------------------
```

and a friendship table:

```
------------------------------------
| status    | playerId  | friendId |
------------------------------------
```

I' am using the following query to retrieve player informations and status of relationship between players:

```
declare @id int = 1

select * from 
(SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    p.email,
    p.email_verified,
    p.gender,
    p.picture,
    f1.playerId,
    f1.friendId,
    f1.status

  FROM players p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN friendships f1
    ON
  f1.playerId = p.id or f1.friendId = p.id) as pl
WHERE
pl.id <> @id
```

The results are the following:

```
id  name        email                       playerId    friendId    status
2   Nina        el@gmail.com                2           1           1
2   Nina        el@gmail.com                2           49          1
49  Ciccio      testpast@gmail.com          2           49          1
```

In this case the user 2 is in friendship with user 1 and with another user, I need to display the first record, since is in relationship with the user id parameter, but I need also to retrieve all users, in friendship and not. 
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` window function

```
select * from (SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    p.email,
    p.email_verified,
    p.gender,
    p.picture,
    f1.playerId,
    f1.friendId,
    f1.status,
    row_number() over(partition by p.id,
    p.name,
    p.email,f1.friendId order by id) rn

  FROM players p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN friendships f1
    ON
  f1.playerId = p.id or f1.friendId = p.id
) t where t.rn=1
```